# Ubuntu 18.04 freezes occasionally but audio keeps playing

Tags: sound, performance

I have encountered freezing several times on a newly installed Ubuntu 18.04 system. At first I thought it might be something wrong with my hard disk. I then replaced it with a new SSD, but the problem still exists.

The audio however, no matter what the length it is, will keeping playing till the end. I can move my mouse cursor over the screen but am unable to click anything on it, and the indicator LEDs on my keyboard won't blink if I press <kbd>NumLock</kbd> or <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> keys.

I once tried letting it hang there for two hours, and it did unfreeze, but it was too long for me to wait. I need to be able to control the audio and switch off when I want to.

Any help will be appreciated.